# Arduino Ethernet Shield client.connect() always returns error

Tags: arduino, ethernet

I have been searching around for this problem for a couple of days but still do not find an answer.

I am trying to make a simple Webclient connection with the arduino shield based on the sample code provided by Arduino IDE. Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to execute:

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>


byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
byte server[] = { 173 ,194, 46, 34 }; // Google

EthernetClient client;

void setup()
{
  Ethernet.begin(mac);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  delay(1000);

  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());

  Serial.println("connecting...");

  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    client.println("GET /search?q=arduino HTTP/1.0");
    client.println();
  } else {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}

void loop()
{
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();
    for(;;)
      ;
  }
}
```

and always get the answer:

```
192.168.0.103
connecting...
connection failed

disconnecting.
```

That means that client.connect(server, 80) is failing. I have tried several IP addresses and same results. The shield is working properly as I have tried the WebServer example and that seems to work flawlessly.

PS on hardware: I am using Arduino UNO R3 and ethernet shield based on W5100

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the [source code](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/Ethernet/src/EthernetClient.h) of the Ethernet library, assuming that you have a recent version of the libraries. It seems to me that Arduino `EthernetClient` `connect()` function wants either an `IPAddress` object or a string (`char *`) with the name of the remote host. You are passing a byte array to it, and my guess is that it probably interprets it as a string.
Try to declare the `server` global variable as follows instead:

```
IPAddress server(173 ,194, 46, 34);
```

If it works, then it is an indication that the [official documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ClientConnect), from which you probably took the code, is obsolete.

Also, you could try giving to the `begin()` function all the other parameters as `IPAddress` objects, so that DHCP is not used and you can rule out problems of automatic configuration. The prototype is:

```
void begin(uint8_t *mac_address, IPAddress local_ip, IPAddress dns_server, IPAddress gateway, IPAddress subnet);
```

Answer (score 1):

sorry for the late reply.

Just add delay of 6 seconds before call to `client.connect()`

so it takes time to initialize ethernet shield....
-by experience

Answer (score 0):

I managed to come with a workaround. It seems client.connect only fails the first time it is called. So I added a dummy call after the 1 second delay (before the real call is made).

This does not answer the question, but it does solve the problem. Any feedback on why this is happening is  welcome.

```
delay(1000);
client.connect(server, 80); // Dummy call
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, my solution was to put all the configuration by myself; google dns(8.8.8.8), gateway, subnet, ip. and I think that the main trick was to have a sweet delay after the Ethernet.begin. I give a 3000 delay so the connection could be established fine and hands'on...

Comment: today i'm reading your comment.. Sorry about that. Finally, did you find a more elegant solution?

Answer (score -1):

I faced the similar problem with my client code until i figured out that it was my antivirus's firewall which was blocking arduino's client to connect.

I added an exception in my antivirus and now it works fine.

Comment: Not sure it s related